# Why does command not work with a command beginning with assignment?

Tags: bash

From Bash Manual:

> command [-pVv] *command* [arguments ...]
>
> Runs command with arguments ignoring any shell function named command.
>   Only shell builtin commands or commands found by searching the PATH
>   are executed. If there is a shell function named ls, running ‘command
>   ls’ within the function will execute the external command ls instead
>   of calling the func- tion recursively. The -p option means to use a
>   default value for PATH that is guaranteed to fi nd all of the standard
>   utilities. The return status in this case is 127 if command cannot be
>   found or an error occurred, and the exit status of command otherwise.

Does the manual explain why it fails when *command* is assignment or begins with assignment (for environment variables)?

```
$ command aaa=1
aaa=1: command not found

$ command aaa=1 echo hello
aaa=1: command not found
```

Comment: Because an assignment is not a command?

Comment: assignment is a simple command.

Comment: By whose definition?

Comment: bash manual or posix

Comment: Quote that definition. Indeed the very part you quote says: "shell builtin commands or commands found by searching the PATH"

Comment: then why doesn't such a command with assignment before it work?

Comment: See my first comment.

Comment: it doesn't answer my last comment.

Comment: Your last comment doesn't contain anything to be answered.

Comment: Yes, it does.,.

Comment: If it does, then it's answered by my first comment.

Comment: you first comment is about a pure assignment. my last comment is a command with assignment before it. How are they on the same page?

Comment: Again from the part you quote: `command [-pVv] *command*`. I don't see anything about variable assignment being allowed there.

Comment: I understand your curiosity, Tim, but when your question is "Does the manual explain why it fails when (I do something)?" I think you're asking for our opinion of the manual, and expecting the manual to explain something above and beyond the shell's syntax. Is it not clear to you from the shell's error message that it's trying to *execute* the intended variable assignment?

Comment: Why closing this question? The question is clear, and the comments posted by the author are clarifying further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confusing what POSIX calls a "simple command" which is a non empty sequence of optional assignments, optional redirections and optional words (including a command name and its optional arguments), and "command" as it is used in the Bash manual `command` synopsis which is here just a command name.

Should you really want to use assignments here, you can simply run :

```
aaa=1 command echo hello
```

If there is no command at all but just an assignment, there is no much point using the `command` command, given the fact there is no builtin or command to search in the PATH in the first place.

Should you really want to just set a variable with `command`, you might use

```
command typeset aaa=1
```

or

```
command declare aaa=1
```

Comment: I wish I could give this more than one upvote.  You said exactly what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

### Use the "let" command (for arithmetic expressions)

The command form of the plain assignment `aaa=1` is `let aaa=1`. However, this applies to arithmetic expressions only (and not to string assignments):

```
$ command let aaa=1
$ echo $aaa
1
$ command let aaa=6*3+5
$ echo $aaa
23
```

Comment: You are misusing `let` here, which evaluates arithmetic expressions (or perhaps confusing it with the BASIC `let` instruction). `command let aaa=hello` would set `aaa` to `0` which is unlikely what the OP expects..