# Is a string an arithmetic expression?

Tags: bash, shell, arithmetic

In Bash, I use a string where an arithmetic expression is expected:

```
$ (( hello ))
$ echo $?
1

$ echo $(( hello ))
0

$ let aaa=hello
$ echo $?
1
$ echo $aaa
0
```

There is no error reported. So is a string an arithmetic expression? If yes, is the value of a string always 0?

My question comes from a comment [Why does command not work with a command beginning with assignment?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278448/why-does-command-not-work-with-a-command-beginning-with-assignment?noredirect=1#comment484115_278453)

Comment: Where's the string?

Comment: `hello` is the string.

Comment: `hello` is the variable name.

Comment: See my edit. `hello` in the new example is a string, is it?

Comment: It's a variable name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In bash arithmetical expressions (e. g. `$((3+2))`), you can, just as with bash writ large, use variables.  However, in this special case, you do not have to use the `$` character to denote variables:

```
ghoti ~$ foo=5
ghoti ~$ echo $((foo))
5
ghoti ~$ echo $((foo*2))
10
ghoti ~$ echo $(($foo*2))
10
```

As mentioned in the comments to your question, `hello` in your case is not the string you think it is, but rather the name of an undefined variable which would have a value of zero.

Comment: Note the difference when `foo=1+1`